# Construct an analytic function which has simple zeros at all $m+in$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, weierstrass-factorization

I found a "duplicate" question: [Entire function having zeros at $m+in$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2639020/entire-function-having-zeros-at-min), and I went through some wiki pages of Weierstrass sigma function, but they don't seem to have constructions.

So basically I'm quite confused with the exponent. We can begin with
$$f(z) = z\prod_{\omega\in\Lambda^*}\left(1-\frac{z}{\omega}\right)\exp(\dots), \quad \Lambda=\Lambda^*\cup\{0\}=\{m+in\} ,$$
also notice that
$$\log\left(1-\frac{z}{\omega}\right) = -\frac{z}{\omega} - \frac{z^2}{2\omega^2} - \dots$$
So why does Weierstrass sigma function put two terms in exponential to get rid of the first two terms? It seems one term is ok to kill all exponent that $\leq 1$.

Is Weierstrass sigma function the "best" construction though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the extra factors in the definition of the Weierstrass
sigma function is to ensure the product converges absolutely.

"Best construction" is subjective of course, but how about
$$(\sin\pi z)\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-e^{-2n\pi}e^{2\pi iz})
(1-e^{-2n\pi}e^{-2\pi iz})?$$